# What tools currently allow to retrieve Windows 10/11 password hashes, given admin rights or physical access to unencrypted disks?

Tags: passwords, hash, windows, physical-access

I was wondering what Windows/Linux/Live tools allow to retrieve user password hashes of modern 2021 Win10/11 installations. I am not sure if password storage differs in these cases (e.g. different location or hash in use) from previous Windows versions (NT hash stored in SAM):

- Microsoft account logged in during installation with account password/Windows Hello access
- Local user created during installation with password and mandatory hint/security questions
- Local user initially created without password, and then added password via Control Panel (no hint/security questions required)
- other setups if any

Comment: Mimikatz did, at least for Windows 10 local accounts. I haven't tested it on Win11, but it should work. I don't know about Microsoft accounts, but I expect it works for them too.

Comment: LaZagne can retreive many passwords stored somewhere in Windows (including User PWs), but it needs to be whitelisted on Windows Defender

Answer (score 2):

[LaZagne](https://github.com/AlessandroZ/LaZagne) can recover all kinds of passwords and password hashes stored in Windows, including browsers, programs (like Skype, Thunderbird etc.), WiFi passwords, **Windows user password hashes** and more.

In order to retreive all windows passwords, just open a shell with admin priviligies and type `LaZagne.exe [module(s)]` to retreive all passwords that the module includes. So in your case **`LaZagne.exe Windows` to retreive all Windows (user) password hashes.**

Table of all modules and passwords that can be recovered ([Source](https://www.kitploit.com/2018/01/lazagne-v23-credentials-recovery-project.html?m=1)):
[image: [Modules]]

This tool works in Windows 10 and should work in Windows 11 aswell, since both operating systems are very similar.

The only disadvantage is that it needs to be manually whitelisted on Windows Defender.

Comment: Only a local user account with single password, getting this: https://imgur.com/a/qcXEXNa

Comment: The Screenshot is really blurry, but I guess it shows besides your name sth like `Administrator [hash]` and `Guest [hash]`. This is normal, although Im not sure what that means, but I guess that These are just hashes of an empty password/No password

Comment: The Administrator account is probably deactivated by Standard in the home Version of Windows and only used by companies etc.  The guest Account is deactivated aswell and can/could be activated in the settings (only tried it in Windows 7 some years ago)